# Conditional Statement returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate an input field with REGEX. Can anyone help me understand why this conditional statement is returning "Wrong" in the console?

```
 <script>
            $('form[action*="paypal"]').submit(function(event) {        

                if (/^DAM\d{10}/.test($('input[name="item_name"]'))){
                    console.log("Correct!");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Wrong!");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        </script>
```

The form im targeting is:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XN4BQ5WSZZCEQ">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" value="">Enter your number</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="item_name" required></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And i'm entering DAM1234567891 into the input field below:

```
  <input type="text" name="item_name" required></td></tr>
```

Comment: What value are you inputting?

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: I'm guessing `$('input[name="item_name"]')` should have a `.val()` attached to the end of it...

Comment: I've edited the question to show you exactly what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
   integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="paypal.php">
   <input name="item_name" value="DAM1234567891" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
   $('form[action*="paypal"]').submit(function(event) {        

       if (/^DAM\d{10}/.test($('input[name="item_name"]').val())){
           console.log("Correct!");
           event.preventDefault();
           return true;
       }
       else {
           console.log("Wrong!");
           event.preventDefault();
       }
   });
</script>
```

Your input will need to start with DAM and have 10 digits.

Comment: Shaun, please give the above a try.

Comment: @Shaun, would you mark this as your best answer? Looks like that my answer may have helped you come up with your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, thanks guys. It worked when i put preventDefault in both statements and return true; above.

```
 <script>
                $('form[action*="paypal"]').submit(function(event) {        

                    if (/^DAM\d{10}/.test($('input[name="item_name"]').val())){
                        console.log("Correct!");
                        return true;
                        event.preventDefault();

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Wrong!");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }

                });
        </script>
```

Comment: You should only need `event.preventDefault()` once, before your `if-else` statements. The one you have in your `if` statement right now will never be called because it's after the `return` statement.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. I did try to think that before i tried this method and i couldn't get it to work. I will have another go shortly and get back to you with the result. thank you